How to limit total power consumption of circuit so I don't overload my power supply
I have a system with ten 110 W fans and a 1 KW PSU.  I will normally have PWM control of those fans to reduce power consumption of the circuit for operational efficiency, but in the event that my controller fails, I would like to make sure that I will not exceed the capacity of the PSU.
Is there a way to limit the total current output of the power supply or perhaps a way to hold the last known state of the fan's PWM signal in a controller loss, or even perhaps a way to default to a constant PWM signal that is less than 100% in the event my controller goes away?
Any and all ideas are welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Damn! If you have a system that requires a kilowatt worth of fans to keep it cool, you need to make very sure that it is as reliable and fail-safe as possible. Start by upgrading the PSU so that it can handle all of the fans at 100% if the controller fails -- and make sure that any controller failure does that. (But is a 10% overload really going to kill it anyway?)

Don't forget to check the fan's specs - is that 110W peak during startup, or typical figure during running? You may also need to stagger the startup, not just manage the fan speed during normal operation.

Good advice and I did already test the fans.  They were spec'd at below 100 W, but testing showed they could go up to 110 W with some added backpressure and at full speed.

Of course there are methods. But without knowing anything about the fans or about your controller, the methods are not yet suggestable. Does your fan turn fully on or fully off if PWM stops, stays low or high, etc?

kW level PSU often have some nice overload protection features, i.e. constant power/current limiting as opposed to hiccup. This would slightly reduce the output voltage to not exceed max current.

Your power supply probably has overcurrent protection but it wouldn't hurt to back it up with a fuse - not as your first line of defense though.
You could put in some sort of watchdog timer on the PWM line to cut power if it doesn't receive an edge after however many milliseconds. This could be done with a simple dedicated chip and would probably be able to react faster than the fan's increase in current. If you need to throttle to zero, just drop the duty cycle to 5% or something under the fan's control threshold.
Another more complicated option would be to use a current sensor as an e-fuse, but this would require more circuitry - a comparator at least.
It's never a great idea to run a power supply at 100% of its rated load for extended periods of time. I would upgrade the supply to give at least a 20% buffer over your maximum continuous power draw (though if you're only operating the fans at 80% then maybe you're fine as-is). Also, the nameplate current draw on fans can be much higher than the actual current draw; measure the actual operating current and you might be far lower then you think.

My problem is I can't lose all the fans and so I want to prevent the PSU from an over current situation that would cause the entire PSU to be shut down.  Holding the last known PWM signal or defaulting to a known value that is <100% would be preferred

You could do something with a MCU to intercept the PWM signal and cap the duty cycle but then you've just kicked the can down the road if you're not confident in your current controller's ability to not fail. There might be something clever you could do with a PLL-ish thing and timers as well but I would take a divide and conquer approach. If you don't want to get a 1200-1500W power supply, then move some of the fans onto another one so that you stay below the limit even at full power. You have 1kW of fans cooling something important and expensive. This is not the place to cut corners.

Additionally, none of the suggestions I made above will actually protect the power supply in case of an overcurrent from a locked rotor, short circuit, etc. Again, if you are cooling something with 1kW of fans, then I strongly suggest a current monitor on the supply to initiate a graceful shutdown before the power supply trips on overcurrent. Other Good Ideas if you haven't included them yet would be individual fan RPM monitoring to detect over/underspeed, individual fusing for each fan, and not just oversized but fully redundant backup power supplies.
